# Filtering dataframe based on that if string is made from specific letters

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

So i have Dataframe that look's like this

**note** i put diffrent letters in * * for you to see easy

```
      id                                                              genome
0    639  ATGTTTGTTTTT*Y*TTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTAT
1    640  ATGTTTGTTTTT*J*TTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTAT
2    641  ATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTAT
3    642  ATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTATATGTTTGTTTTTCTTGTTTTAT
```

I want to filter it by string. Basically if string contains any other letter than A, C, T, G, N leave this row in dataframe else **just delete it**.

I was tying this

```py
df = df[~df['genome'].str.contains('[^ACTGN]')]
```

and this

```
df = df[df['genome'].str.match('^[ACTGN]+$')]
```

but nothings seams to work, all i get is all rows are true or false despite having diffrent letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your strings have leading/trailing spaces (look at those alignments in print out). So try:

```
df['genome'] = df['genome'].str.strip()
df = df[~df['genome'].str.contains('[^ACTGN]')]
```

Or you can chain them if you don't want to modify your `genome` column:

```
df = df[df[~df['genome'].str.strip().str.contains('[^ACTGN]')]
```

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, genome]
Index: []  - i get this all the time and i don't know why

Comment: Please check again, this works for sample data.

Comment: Do you have linkedin or you can msg on stack it's straight up not working